# Why am I getting this WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application?

Tags: android

I am working on a way for a user to enter their username into my app, however I am getting this exception. Here is my code:

```
package myPackage;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context myAppContext;
    private String username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myAppContext = getApplicationContext();

        // Username Input Dialog
        final EditText userInput = new EditText(this);
        final SharedPreferences myAppPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        final TextView usernameTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username_box);

        username = myAppPreferences.getString("username", null);

        usernameTextview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(username != null){
                    userInput.setText(username);
                }

                AlertDialog.Builder inputAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(myAppContext);
                inputAlert.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_50x50);
                inputAlert.setTitle("Username");
                inputAlert.setMessage("Please enter your username.");
                inputAlert.setView(userInput);
                inputAlert.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.STANDARD_FILE_TIMESTAMP, Locale.US);
                        username = (!userInput.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) ? userInput.getText().toString() : Constants.TABLET_ID;
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myAppPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("username", username);
                        editor.putString("log-in date", sdf.format(new Date()));
                        editor.apply();
                        usernameTextview.append(username);
                    }
                });
                inputAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        usernameTextview.append(username);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = inputAlert.create();
                // THE FOLLOWING LINE IS WHERE I GET MY WindowManager$BadTokenException
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

        if(username != null){
            usernameTextview.append(username);
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder inputAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            inputAlert.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_50x50);
            inputAlert.setTitle("Username");
            inputAlert.setMessage("Please enter your username.");
            inputAlert.setView(userInput);
            inputAlert.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.STANDARD_FILE_TIMESTAMP, Locale.US);
                    username = (!userInput.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) ? userInput.getText().toString() : Constants.TABLET_ID;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myAppPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("username", username);
                    editor.putString("log-in date", sdf.format(new Date()));
                    editor.apply();
                    usernameTextview.append(username);
                }
            });
            inputAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    usernameTextview.append(username);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = inputAlert.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

I have labeled the line where I am getting my exception.

**EDIT:**

Here is the new error I am getting after changing my code from

```
AlertDialog.Builder inputAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder inputAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

I also moved this statement to immediately after the statement:

```
final TextView usernameTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username_box);
```

And I removed the duplicates in the code.

logcat:

```
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a7c1f8)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3337)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3208)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3188)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:401)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:241)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:336)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:353)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:257)

E/AndroidRuntime:     at myPackage.main.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:138)

E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Activity context` when creating `AlertDialog`

```
AlertDialog.Builder inputAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivity.this);
```

Comment: That worked well ... sort of. Now I get an error on that line that says "IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first". I can call it once just fine. But when I try to call it a second time, that is when I get the error.

Comment: @Brian Why you created two `inputAlert` ?

Comment: I need it in both places. I need to have the input alert show if there is no username in the shared preferences, and I need to have the alert show if a user clicks the button to change the existing username in the shared preferences. I moved the inputAlert creation to just below "final TextView usernameTextview ..." and removed it from the two duplicate places, but I still get the same error.

Comment: I have added the logcat.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post my final solution to my problem. Thanks to user [M D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d) I was able to fix my original problem. After some googling I was able to fix my subsequent problem of

> "IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first"

I did this by moving the EditText declarations.

```
package myPackage;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final SharedPreferences myAppPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        final TextView usernameTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username_box);

        username = myAppPreferences.getString("username", null);

        usernameTextview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final EditText userInput = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                if(username != null){
                    userInput.setText(username);
                }

                AlertDialog.Builder inputAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                inputAlert.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_50x50);
                inputAlert.setTitle("Username");
                inputAlert.setMessage("Please enter your username.");
                inputAlert.setView(userInput);
                inputAlert.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.STANDARD_FILE_TIMESTAMP, Locale.US);
                        username = (!userInput.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) ? userInput.getText().toString() : Constants.TABLET_ID;
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myAppPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("username", username);
                        editor.putString("log-in date", sdf.format(new Date()));
                        editor.apply();
                        usernameTextview.setText(username);
                    }
                });
                inputAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        usernameTextview.setText(username);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = inputAlert.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

        if(username != null){
            usernameTextview.setText(username);
        } else {
            final EditText userInput = new EditText(this);
            AlertDialog.Builder inputAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            inputAlert.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_50x50);
            inputAlert.setTitle("Username");
            inputAlert.setMessage("Please enter your username.");
            inputAlert.setView(userInput);
            inputAlert.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.STANDARD_FILE_TIMESTAMP, Locale.US);
                    username = (!userInput.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) ? userInput.getText().toString() : Constants.TABLET_ID;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myAppPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("username", username);
                    editor.putString("log-in date", sdf.format(new Date()));
                    editor.apply();
                    usernameTextview.setText(username);
                }
            });
            inputAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    usernameTextview.setText(Constants.TABLET_ID);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = inputAlert.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```